# Is possible get ring tone,touch tone and linked contacts with all contact details using Contact Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontact

Hi i am trying to get all contact details into my app.But in this i got all contact details (Givenname,Familyname,Organization and etc...) except ring tone,touch tone and linked contacts.

Is possible get these 3 (ring tone,touch tone and linked contacts) fields into my app,if possible please suggest me how to get these fields.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to get the ringtone and touch tone for contact. But it is possible to get the linked contacts. Using [ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople) Although it is deprecated and apple doc says to use `[CNContainer predicateForContainerOfContactWithIdentifier:]` i am unable to get proper documentation for that.